# Get the sum of rows when a rule is triggered

Tags: excel, google-drive-api

In google drive I have an excel file with many rows. In one column you can choose from a list of values `office`, `home`, `other` and in another column I have some numbers. How can I choose all theses rows which have the value `home` and then get the `sum` of the next column which has the numbers?

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en

Comment: thx! I found it `=SUMIFS(C2:C36, B2:B36, "=home")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to @Robin the answer is https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496?hl=en

```
=SUMIFS(C2:C36, B2:B36, "=home")
```